# Getting static data from a json file into backbone model

Tags: json, url, backbone.js, model, fetch

I have the following code and was wondering why my data isn't getting pulled into my model? I'm using a static json file and I'm guessing this might be my problem but can't seem to find any documentation about it.

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initiliazed model')
    },

    url: "data/data.json"

});

var StructureView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initiliazed view')
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.model.fetch();
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change',this.render);
    },
    el : '#ev-wrapper',
    render: function () {
        $('#ev-wrapper').empty().append(Handlebars.compile($('#ev-template').html())(this.model.toJSON()));
        $('.ev-asset-loader').fadeOut('slow');
    }

});

var structureView = new StructureView({model: new DataModel()});
```

Comment: Can you see the data being received on your dev tools?

Comment: I can...and stupidly realised that I was loading my old json file. Just as a quick question - If I used model.save() will this write a new json file?

Comment: no it will not write a new json file. model.save() will send a POST request if the model doesn't exist or a PUT if it exists already. (it checks for a model id by default to determine this). Have a look at using localstorage in the meantime if you want to test it locally and write new changes, etc

Comment: Thanks...I feel like there's not enough documentation about model and view relationships - My app will hardly use collections - so all the turotials tend to use collections.

Comment: it just takes awhile to wrap your head around, we've all been there. good luck writing your first backbone app!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `fetch`. This will issue an AJAX request using `url`

```
var model = new DataModel();
model.fetch();
```

Open Firebug or your favorite browser's network console to see AJAX requests and check if it's OK